# Prove triangle inequality on $\hat{N}(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 + xy + y^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm having problems to demonstrate triangle inequality on the above function. So far I've tried:

\begin{align}
\hat{N}(u+v) &= \hat{N}((u_1, u_2)+ (v_1,v_2))\\
&= \hat{N}((u_1+v_1, u_2+v_2))\\
&= \sqrt{(u_1+v_1)^2+(u_1+v_1)(u_2+v_2)+(u_2+v_2)^2}\\
&= \sqrt{(u_1^2+u_1u_2+u_2^2) + (v_1^2+v_1v_2+v_2^2) + 2(u_1v_1+u_2v_2) + u_1v_2 + u_2v_1}
\end{align}

---

For the restant terms inside the square root, using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have that:
\begin{align}
|2(u_1v_1 + u_2v_2)| &\leq 2(u_1^2+u_2^2)(v_1^2+v_2^2)\\
|u_1v_2 + u_2v_1| &\leq (u_1^2+u_2^2)(v_1^2+v_2^2)
\end{align}
Summing up the inequalities:
\begin{align}
|2(u_1v_1 + u_2v_2)| + |u_1v_2 + u_2v_1| &\leq 3(u_1^2+u_2^2)(v_1^2+v_2^2)
\end{align}
Using that $ |a+b| \leq |a| + |b|$:
\begin{align}
|2(u_1v_1 + u_2v_2) + u_1v_2 + u_2v_1| &\leq 3(u_1^2+u_2^2)(v_1^2+v_2^2)
\end{align}

Maybe it could be of some help, but I'm stuck from this point.

Comment: The triangle inequality applies because this is just the standard Euclidean norm in a different basis: $$x^2+xy+y^2=\big(x+y/2\big)^2+\big(y\sqrt3/2\big)^2$$ If $N$ is any norm and $L$ is any invertible linear transformation, then $N\circ L$ is also a norm.

Comment: Nice fact, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $B(u,v)=u_1v_1+\frac{1}{2}(u_2v_1+u_1v_2)+u_2v_2$ and $B(u)=B(u,u).$ Observe that
$$B\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{B(u)}}-\frac{v}{\sqrt{B(v)}}\right)=2-2\frac{B(u,v)}{\sqrt{B(u)}\sqrt{B(v)}}\geq 0.$$ Hence
$$B(u+v)=B(u)+B(v)+2B(u,v)\leq \left(\sqrt{B(u)}+\sqrt{B(v)}\right)^2.$$

Comment: Thanks! It helped me a lot. Accepting your answer.